# Django ORM apply .filter() to an existing queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I'm a bit confused about requests into database to be executed in this code snippet

```
>>> from core.models import People
>>> p = People.objects.all()
>>> p.filter(age__gt=10)
```

It's clear that passing `objects.all()` into ORM will lead to one request like `SELECT *`

However, if I apply `.filter()` method to an existing queryset, will it lead to second request to database?
Or ORM will look through the existing queryset?

Thank you

Comment: querysets are lazy:: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy

Answer (score 3):

> However, if I apply `.filter()` method to an existing queryset, will it lead to second request to database?

constructing querysets will *not* make a database query. Indeed, here `p = People.objects.all()` will *not* make a query.

Querysets will make a query if you "*consume*" the queryset. You consume the queryset if you iterate over it, call `len(…)`, `str(…)` en `repr(…)` over it, etc.

This thus means that if you print `p.filter(age__gt=10)`, it will *only* make a query with `SELECT people.* FROM people WHERE age > 10`. If you later for example print `p`, it will make a second query `SELECT people.* FROM people`.

Querysets also cache the result when they are *consumed*. So if you iterate a second time on the same `QuerySet`, it will reuse the result of the previous query.

Comment: Could you also tell me if I "consume" a variable where the queryset has been already stored, will django make an additional query? I mean len(p) in my example. I think that only len(People.objects.all()) will run a query

Comment: @fghfgg: `len(p)` will consume the query, but if you for example already enumerated over the query, it will thus reuse the result cache, and not make a second query.

Comment: @fghfgg: as a rule of thumb if you need data out of the queryset it will make a query, if it already has the data, then it will not make a second request.